# How to add a background to a boostrap grid row (including padding!)?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, background, grid

I'm quite new to bootstrap, but I'm beginning to like the grid system.

I've created a test layout. The only thing I haven't accomplished by now, is putting a background around some row.

How can I have some padding on the left and the right?

Here's my example:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link href="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container" id="container">
            <div id="header" class="row">
                <div class="span12">Hallo123</div>
            </div>
            <div id="main" class="row">
                <div class="span10" id="one">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="span2">Hallo1</div>
                        <div class="span2">Hallo2</div>
                        <div class="span2">Hallo3</div>
                        <div class="span2">Hallo4</div>
                        <div class="span2">Hallo5</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="span2" id="two">Hallo2</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#main {
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px #888;
}

#header .span12 {
    background-color: #DD1144;
}

#container {
    background-color: #DF8505;
}

#one, #two, #three, #four {
    background-color: #0088CC;
}
```

Comment: Can you specify what do you mean by "padding"? Is it all the space between the row and the border of the viewport? or some space defined by `padding` CSS style?

Comment: Of course. I made a little graphic for explaining, what I want to accomplish: http://img163.imageshack.us/img163/6547/unbenannthrt.png I want the red "frame" around a certain row inside the container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this helps:
http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/JAFPq/

In simple cases where you need to extend the background beyound the width of the bootstrap grid, you could certainly do it by setting negative margins. This wouldn't work so well if you want the background to cover the entire width of the screen though, and it starts getting complicated as the grid collapses on narrow screens.

The best general solution I have found is to close the bootstrap container div just before the area where you want the background. Then start a new bootstrap container for the area where you need the background and wrap this in it's own div which are are free to manipulate however you want.

```
<div class="container" id="container">
        <div id="header" class="row">
            <div class="span12">Hallo123</div>
        </div><!-- end header -->
</div><!-- end container -->

<div class="backgroundHere"><!-- start of div where you want the background -->
<div class="container">     
        <div id="main" class="row">
            <div class="span10" id="one">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="span2">Hallo1</div>
                    <div class="span2">Hallo2</div>
                    <div class="span2">Hallo3</div>
                    <div class="span2">Hallo4</div>
                    <div class="span2">Hallo5</div>
                </div><!-- end nested row -->
            </div><!-- end span 10 -->

            <div class="span2" id="two">Hallo2</div>

        </div><!-- end row -->
 </div><!-- end container -->
 </div><!-- end backgroundHere -->

<!-- you could open another bootstrap container here if you have more content without the background -->
```

Depending on the specifics of your background, you may need to also use @media requests to specify what happens at wide and narrow screens, for example the box-shaddow padding in your case.

Good luck

Comment: At first glance, it seems to be great :) I'll check it out on monday and tick it as the best answer. Also thanks for remembering me of the opportunity to have multiple container elements :)